# Showing data in TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Controller

```
public IActionResult Take() {
.......
List<List<string>> arrayList = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> brandList = new List<string>();
....
TempData["car_list"] = arrayList;
TempData["brand_list"] = brandList;
.......
return RedirectToAction("Result");
}
```

[image]

[image]

**arrayList like this**

```
[{"item","item2","item5"}, {"item5","item4"}, {"item3","item","item5"}]
```

Result View

```
@foreach (var item in TempData["car_list"] as IEnumerable<string>)
{
    @item
}
</div>
```

I want to show it like this on the "View"

```
<p>item, item2, item5</p>
<p>item5, item4 </p>
<p>item3, item, item5 </p>
```

I get the following error.
[image]

How can I show my values on the "View"

#### Update

Controller

```
    TempData["car_list"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrayList);
```

View -> I'm getting an error here.

cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

```
@{ 
var rm =Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
<List<List<string>>>(TempData["car_list"]);
}

    <div>
        @foreach (var item in rm)
        {
            <span>@string.Join(",", item)</span><br>
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: Your starting point is, ermm, less than optimal. Send car *objects* to the view instead of arrays of strings. A car object is an instance of a car *class*.

Comment: @GertArnold I am new I did not fully understand. I would be glad if you could give an example. Thanks

Comment: You work with C#. That's your choice. But then you need at least some basic understanding of the language you're using. Concepts like classes, objects, and instances belongs to this basic understanding. We can't help you if we can't communicate on this basic level.

Comment: @GertArnold I move these arrays to another View. I redirect the arrays I created in this action(ActionResult Take) to the "Result" view. Is this possible without TempData? I updated controller.

Comment: Note: There is more than one TempData in Action, but I cannot show only car_list in Result view.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems that you are using TempData to store a `List<List<string>>()` object, so, in the view, you could convert the TempData to `List<List<string>>` or `IEnumerable<List<string>>`. Code as below (using the `string.Join()` method to add separator):

```
@foreach (var item in TempData["car_list"] as List<List<string>>)
{
  <span>@string.Join(",", item)</span><br>
}
```

Code in the controller:

```
        List<List<string>> arrayList = new List<List<string>>();
        arrayList.Add(new List<string>() { "item", "item2", "item5" });
        arrayList.Add(new List<string>() { "item5", "item4" });
        arrayList.Add(new List<string>() { "item3", "item", "item5" });
        TempData["car_list"] = arrayList;
```

The result like this:

[image]

**Edit:**

If you want to serialize the array list, you could refer the following code:

Code in the action method:

```
    public IActionResult Take()
    {
        List<List<string>> arrayList = new List<List<string>>();

        arrayList.Add(new List<string>() { "item", "item2", "item5" });
        arrayList.Add(new List<string>() { "item5", "item4" });
        arrayList.Add(new List<string>() { "item3", "item", "item5" }); 
        // TempData["car_list"] = arrayList; 
        TempData["car_list"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrayList);

        return View();
    }
```

Code in the view:

```
<div>  
    @{
        var rm = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(TempData["car_list"].ToString());
    }

    <div>
        @foreach (var item in rm)
        {
            <span>@string.Join(",", item)</span><br>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

The output like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I still get the same error. I tried this solution but still didn't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528508/asp-net-core-tempdata-and-redirecttoaction-not-working

Comment: @tomclack In the controller action method, did you serialize the list? Please check my controller code, I just set the TempData using the arrayList, doesn't serialize the list. Besides, try to install the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" using the following command:`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`, then, you’ll probably have one of the following: `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(); services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();`

Comment: It didn't work. I tried to serialize as above but got an error. I updated the question.

Comment: @tomclack I have modified the reply, if you serialize the arraylist, in the View, you should get the json string first, then, use the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to convert the json string to List.